# Use second Gmail account as default mailto in Firefox

Tags: firefox, gmail, mailto

## Problem

I would like `mailto:` links to use my second Gmail account (`.../mail/u/1`) instead of my primary account to send emails by default. Ideally I would not like to change the order my accounts are logged in as, because I use my primary account for search history, maps, etc. Typically, though, I use my second account (work account) for email.

I'm using Firefox 38.0/Firefox for Ubuntu canonical 1.0 on Ubuntu Trusty (14.04).

## I've tried...

I've searched both SU and the web generally and found plenty of mentions of using Gmail as the default app for `mailto`. I've got this working, so this is not my issue.

I've tried opening `about:config` and editing `gecko.handlerService.schemes.mailto.1.uriTemplate` from:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail?extsrc=mailto&url=%s
```

to

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1?extsrc=mailto&url=%s
```

I've done this, closed Firefox and restarted, and tried a URL but even with this value saved Gmail uses my default account.

I have searched for an answer to my issue and I've read the help files!

Does anyone know if there's a way to achieve this without changing the order of logins?

Comment: I could not get @phil solution (editing mimetTypes.rdf) to work on 68.0.2. However, edititing the handlers.json with the same code did the trick!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @DanCornilescu for his suggestion which got me started along these lines.

I noticed that changes I made in `about:config` to `gecko.handlerService.schemes.mailto.1.uriTemplate' were not affecting the 'Application details' in Preferences > Applications > Mailto.

After a bit of digging I found that application preferences are set in `mimeTypes.rdf` in the Firefox profile. To change it:

1. Open your profile folder by opening `about:support` in a new tab.
2. Under 'Profile directory' click 'Open directory'
3. Close Firefox
4. Create a backup of `mimeTypes.rdf`. I just copied a version to my desktop in case. If you follow this steps without a backup and screw up, don't blame me.
5. Edit `mimeTypes.rdf` in a plain text editor like Notepad++ or gedit.
6. Search for the offending `mailto` item. I simply did a find for 'mail.google.com' and found the appropriate `uriTemplate` listing
7. Edit the URL here. You can add `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/?authuser=me@gmail.com&amp;extsrc=mailto&amp;url=%s` or `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1?extsrc=mailto&amp;url=%s` Both also worked for a Google Apps email address (i.e. a gmail account without the .gmail.com domain)
8. Save the `mimeTypes.rdf` file and reload Firefox.

`mailto:` links should now use your second gmail account by default.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking around how to open an email with a particular gmail account, this is the only (or first) place I found the authuser param. Very useful

Answer (score 1):

Try to add **authuser=account2@gmail.com** to the url's parameters. Seems to be working for reading email according to the selected A to this Q:

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18959/can-i-form-a-direct-url-to-a-particular-gmail-account

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This didn't work when changing the value in `about:config` but I was able to use it in `mimeTypes.rdf` (see my answer)